# complete compact open topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ denotes a path-connected and compact manifold and $PX$ its path-space (the set of continuous maps $\gamma: [0,1] \longrightarrow X$) topologized with the compact open topology. It is true that $PX$ is complete? 
Can we refine the assumptions on $X$ such that $PX$ still complete?

Comment: Complete in what sense? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_topological_space

Comment: Yes, complete as metrizable space (since $X$ is compact)

Answer (score 1):

Equip $X$ with a complete metric and define a metric on the path space as
$$
d(\gamma,\tau)=\sup_td(\gamma(t),\tau(t)).
$$
Then $PX$ is complete in this metric, as for any Cauchy sequence $\gamma_n$ the the $\gamma_n(t)$ form Cauchy sequences in $X$, hence converge to some $\gamma(t)$.
Now $\gamma_n$ converges uniformly to $\gamma$, so $\gamma$ is continuous again. so lies in $PX$.

Comment: And then check that this metric topology on $PX$ is the same as the compact-open topology (which is certainly true and not hard).

Comment: Thanks, I think the two topologies are the same since $X$ is compact.But what about the non compact case?

Comment: If $X$ is any metric space and $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then the compact-open topology on the space of continuous maps $Y \to X$ agrees with the sup-norm metric topology. This is a classical fact. Then apply this to $Y = [0, 1]$. (And if $Y$ is CH and $X$ is a complete metric space, then the sup-norm metric space of continuous maps $Y \to X$ is complete.) I think all this is in Kelley's topology book, and even generalized to the context of uniform spaces.

Comment: Every metrics which induces compact topology is complete--there is no need to make an additional assumptions.